# Is a Waterfall model an Incremental development model?

Tags: models, iteration, waterfall

I was wondering if a Waterfall model is an incremental model because technically each phase of the Waterfall model adds on a little more.

Thus saying this I have read from quite a few different websites that it is not incremental.

Can someone please provide examples of both Iterative and Incremental models as I find the 2 a bit confusing?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Royce himself didn't believe that waterfall could be a simple phased process - http://securesoftwaredev.com/2010/01/16/waterfall-vs-agile/

Comment: Are you asking about reality or what the "authorities" say?  In reality, every development model is incremental, just some admit it more than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Waterfall model is neither Incremental nor Iterative because it develops the whole system at once, without any increments or iterations.

Answer (score 4):

In Waterfall, you do all of the analysis, then you do all of the design, then you do all of the coding, then you do all of the testing.  It is not incremental because at each phase everything from the previous phase has to be complete.  The problem with Waterfall is that there is no feedback throughout the process.  If requirements change or some assumption turns out to be wrong, these usually don't get discovered until after the all the work is done and the product is delivered to the customer for the first time.  At that point it is often more difficult and costly to make changes.

In an incremental model, you do a little analysis, a little design, a little coding and a little testing, then, after getting feedback from the customer, you go back and do a little more analysis, a little more design, a little more coding, a little more testing etc.  So the product is built incrementally over many iterations of this process.  The idea is to get feedback early and often so that you aren't wasting a bunch of time and effort building something that the customer isn't ultimately going to be happy with.  Agile and Scrum are examples of incremental models.

Answer (score 1):

[Not incremental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development#Contrast_with_Waterfall_development).

The waterfall model assumes that you are God and therefore can predict everything. Also that the customer knows what they want. Often at least one of the above is false.

Iteration: think small waterfalls, which better allows for altering the Big Plan to fit a changing reality.

Incremental: very often seen in conjunction with iterative models. Start with a core and add functionality rather than delivering the whole thing at once.

As for examples, most anything with [agile] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) in it will be both incremental and iterative.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Ryman, Waterfall model is neither iterative or incremental. You can find clear explanation of [iterative model](http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-iterative-model-advantages-disadvantages-and-when-to-use-it/) and [incremental model](http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-incremental-model-advantages-disadvantages-and-when-to-use-it/) on this site.

As shown on the site, in a waterfall model you would have the whole picture at once, though it may or may not look like the Monalisa.